# .htaccess and rewrite from subdirectories inside unknown parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I have an htaccess file in a subdirectory and whenever I try to rewrite the url, it redirects to the document_root and not the subdirectory where the htaccess resides. Now, under normal circumstances, I'd rewrite it with the path to the subdirectory with `path/to/subdirectory`, but I won't know what the exact path will be. Is there a way either, through an Apache environment variable or something else, to write out that path?

Edit:
Here's the `.htaccess` file so far.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule (.*-file) a/b/c/$1.file
    RewriteRule (.*-file) $1.file
```

So, I'm trying to, if the request contains the word `file`, I want to match the entire request prior to the word file and redirect there. This is so that if a request is to

```
    example.com/a/b/c/file[any characters here].file
```

the request will be redirected to the right file. To reiterate, the problem is that I am trying to redirect within the subdirectory. So when I say Rewrite $1, I want that to include the entire request and not just what matched in the REQUEST_FILENAME. And the reason I need it to do that is because I can't simply put `a/b/c/$1.file` since I won't know for absolute certainty the `a/b/c` part.

Edit 2: Examples:
So, an example is that I'd send a request like:

```
    example.com/a/b/c/fileacs.file
```

And want to redirect to:

```
    example.com/a/b/c/file.file
```

Where I do not know a/b/c/. I have an actual regex and set of rules for the real-world use of this redirect, so don't mind the ridiculous nature of this example.

But currently it's redirecting to:

```
    example.com/file.file
```

Which does not exist and even if it did, I do not want to redirect there.  I've read about Rewrite Context, but can't find out anything substantial about it nor if it's the cause for this. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Can you show your .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava I'd have to be home, but I'll make sure to edit my main post to show what I've got so far for sure.

Comment: @anubhava I edited the post to add clarity and context.

Comment: Please give an example of: 1) a matched path (real example, like `a/b/c/file`  ), 2) what it **should** rewrite to, and 3) what it **currently** rewrites to. Thx

Comment: @PaoloStefan I added examples of 1) what I'm matching 2) where it should be rewriting too and 3) where it currently rewrites too. I hope this helps clarify what my problem is and what I'm asking about.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava the .htaccess is located in the subdirectory. So it's located in example.com/a/b/c. It's in the same directory as file.file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule to capture any path before `fileacs.file` and use that as bach-reference in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ^(.*)/file[^.]+\.file$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/file.file [L,R=302]
```

Comment: You're answer got me close to my solution, but it was also matching the part of the request I was trying to omit, but thank you very much!

Comment: I am only trying to capture the path, which I don't know, with my regex.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the a RewriteCond on the %{REQUEST_URI} (thanks anubhava!) that checks matches the entire request except for the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} without capturing it, using a lookahead. Write out this with the %1 followed by the desired filename. See the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)-file(?!\.file) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1.file [L,R=301]
```

The %1 now holds the path up to the directory that the .htaccess is stored, plus any prefix to the filename. This doesn't match the remainder of the request, but rather looksahead to ensure you're not actually requesting the file you would like to redirect to (causing a loop).